# Angular ajax call after clicking on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

i want to make a CRUD part in my app for admin  console. I am using mongodb, spring, bootstrap and angular. I have a list of radio buttons on left which contains names of collections(numers of collections is variable) and on right a data tabel with documents from that datatable which is not implemented yet. The logic is : admin click on a radio button from the left, after that i want to send a ajax call to the server with the name of radio button and the respond will contain the documents from that collection.

Till now, i have :

jsp content:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/includes/script/header.jsp"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/res/custom_script/admin/main.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/res/custom_script/admin/common_admin_all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module("mainAdmin", [])
        .controller("collectionsArray", function($scope) {
            $scope.colnames = ${collectionNames};
        });
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main admin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="mainAdmin">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <p class="logout_paragraph">Logged as <strong>${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}</strong> | <a id="logout_link" onclick="formSubmit()">Logout</a></p>
    <form action="/logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </form>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Welcome !</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="divchkCollections" class="admin_left_menu pre-scrollable col-md-2">
        <div ng-controller="collectionsArray" id="chkCollections" class="admin_collection_list radio">
            <h4>Collections</h4>
                <label ng-repeat="colname in colnames">
                    <input type="radio" name="chkCollectionsRadio" value="{{colname}}" class="radio-button"> {{colname}}
                </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="admin_data_table" class="col-md-10">


    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i make logic from above ? To send an ajax call with the name of the radio to server when admin clicks on it ? The list of names is in collectionNames and is variable in leght and names.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an ng-change argument to the radio button code that calls a function in your javascript code with a reference to the radio button that was changed.

Comment: And you should have a function that can access your data with the passed reference from the front-end in the behind-the-scenes code.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a function to the radio button using the directive ng-change, then bind the value of the radio button to a variable using ng-model:

When you click the radio button the function will be called, and the value of the radio button is in the variable that you bind in ng-model.

```
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="red" ng-model="valueSelected" ng-change="onClick()">
```

then in your controller, make the ajax call in the function that you assign to the radio button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module("mainAdmin", [])
    .controller("collectionsArray", function($scope) {
        $scope.colnames = ${collectionNames};

  //function binded to the radio button on change
  $scope.onClick = function (){
      //alert to test that you send the radio button value
      alert($scope.valueSelected);
      //ajax call
      $.ajax(
      {url: "test", 
      success: function(data){


     }});
  }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: "onClick()" function work, but "$scope.valueSelected" doesn't, i get "undefined" in alert